# I am using ALDEx package for analysis of PICRUST2 output and gave me an error

Tags: r, bioinformatics, qiime

I am following the tutorial below in the link:

https://ycl6.github.io/16S-Demo/4_picrust2_tutorial.html

after copying this code :

```
# EC
set.seed(12345)
system.time({
        aldex2_EC1 = aldex(p2EC1, sample_data(ps1a)$Group, mc.samples = 500, test = "t", 
               effect = TRUE, denom = "iqlr", verbose = TRUE)
})
```

it gives me an error : Error in aldex.clr.function(as.data.frame(reads), conds, mc.samples, denom, :
mismatch between number of samples and condition vector.

I am working on 5 or 6 samples..
I don't know what is the cause of the error

I have no solution in google.

Comment: when i changed mc.samples to 6 or 5 it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can use pathway_daa() in [ggpicrust2](https://github.com/cafferychen777/ggpicrust2) package. It support tens of DA methods include ALDEx2 and it works very easier.